# Error when show posts from another category in sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I did this to show 5 posts of a diferent category in my wordpress page:

```
<?php $archive_query = new WP_Query('category_name=anc&showposts=5');
while ($archive_query->have_posts()) : $archive_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="collection">
<a href="http://mywordpresspage.com/?p=6884" class="collection-item blue-text" style="text-align:center;">See All</a> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>">
          <span class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">

        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Ver más</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

It worked, however, now my another pages don´t work, they show posts from that category when i click on those pages instead of showing their respectives posts, what could be the issue?

Comment: That is because you have "category_name=anc" hard coded and that needs to be dynamic - something like https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset data in the global $post object after endwhile;

```
<?php

while( $your_query->have_posts() ):
 ...
endwhile; 

wp_resest_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to a solution, after the following line:

```
 <?php endwhile;?>
```

I wrote this:

```
 <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

It resets the query so like that the main loop ( because it´s depend of the main loop ) can work perfectly, i hope this helps everyone, this code is an easy way to show any post of a different category.

Comment: `wp_reset_query()` is not necessary in this case. Acording Codex: `"This function should be called after query_posts()".`
`"Calling wp_reset_query is not necessary after using WP_Query or get_posts as these don't modify the main query object. Instead use wp_reset_postdata"`

Comment: @pgk is like you said, the better option if to use :

    <?php wp_reset_postadata(); ?>